# Adjustable mid-line knot?

Tags: ropes, knots

I'm looking for a knot similar to a [sheepshank](http://www.animatedknots.com/sheepshank/) but adjustable and stable under load on both ends.

Think of two poles that have the two ends of a rope permanently attached to them but you want to shorten the rope in-between like you would do with a taut-line hitch. Obviously, you have no free ends for a taut-line. A sheepshank would at least shorten the rope mid-line but could not create tension like a taut-line hitch would.

I feel like there should be a knot for this but I haven't seen one like it yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Knots by Grog](http://www.animatedknots.com/sheepshank/) say:

> If you are asked to learn to tie the Sheepshank, please request your
>   Troop Leader to eliminate this knot and replace it with something safe
>   and useful, e.g., the **Alpine Butterfly Loop** is an excellent way of
>   creating a loop in the middle of a length of rope and can also be
>   safely used to shorten a rope.

So it sounds like you want an

---

### [Alpine Butterfly Loop](http://www.animatedknots.com/alpinebutterfly/index.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com)

Tying it:

> There are several methods for tying it. We devised the method that is
>   used in the animation. It is an improvement on other "hand-winding"
>   methods. It helps locate the loop: the second crossing of your hand is
>   near your fingertips and away from the other two turns. This helps you
>   to locate it, pick it up, and wrap it around the other two strands.
>   Setting the knot usually requires holding the loop in your teeth and
>   pulling both ends with your hands.

If you need tension then you could also try:

### [Truckers Hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/truckers/index.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com)

> Form a bight in the standing end and use it to tie a Directional
>   Figure 8 Knot. Pass the tail round the hook below and through the
>   Directional Figure 8 Loop, and pull tight. Complete the knot with two
>   Half Hitches below the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the Alpine Butterfly and usually use it for this very purpose for lack of a better knot. The problem with it is you can't create tension on the rope like with a taut-line hitch. You end up with a shorter, but still slack rope.

Comment: What about a [truckers hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/truckers/index.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com) then @smossum?

Comment: Oh man, that is genius. I didn't think of using a trucker's hitch on a bight but it works perfectly fine. Alpine Butterfly as the top loop and then just pull a bight through the loop, pull tight, and finish with a few half hitches. Big thanks!

Comment: While the Sheepshank is not useful in this position, it is a good knot to know for other uses and it is a good teaching tool for a whole series of mid line knots.

Answer (score 0):

The basic sheep shank is pretty useless - but if you add a second half hitch to each end and have a decent sized loop out of each end it works great. This is not far off a redirect used by tree climbers... so is head and shoulderr s above the basic sheep shank.