# How to tie a figure eight on a bight?

Tags: climbing, knots

One of the more common knots in climbing is the figure eight on a bight (being tied on a bight means that it is tied without using the ends.

How exactly would one tie this knot?

Comment: Related: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16272/how-do-you-tie-in-to-the-centre-of-a-rope?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you take the bight and bring the end down.

[image]

Then you take the end and cross it over.

[image]

Then bring it back around underneath the main strand.

[image]

Finally take the end through the top loop.

[image]

and there you have it. Before using you would want to dress it and tighten it down.

If you want to see a video of the process for tying this knot, [see the one here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4UhPGC1_Cc).